# beforeunload text ignored in favor of some other text

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have the following JavaScript to detect when a user is leaving my page with unsaved changes.

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (modified) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = 'Your changes have not been saved.';
    }
});
```

But the text displayed doesn't match my text.

[image]

I'm using Microsoft Edge. From what I've read, it should display my text. Has something changed here? Perhaps an increased security concern?

Comment: The original implementations used the return value as a prompt. This has changed so it just checks whether it's empty. If not, the browser displays an implementation-dependant prompt.

Comment: See the **Note** [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#the-beforeunloadevent-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#browser_compatibility), we can know that `event.returnValue = "string";` is deprecated. It's not supported in modern browsers.

[Compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#compatibility_notes) also says:

> Since Firefox 44, Chrome 51, Opera 38, and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage is shown instead of the returned string.

Edge browser is based on chromium so it's the same situation.